# What did I just do with my git repository?

Tags: git

I cloned a git repo and it had, among many others, these two remote branches:

1. master
2. origin/foo-bar

When I cloned it, I was on master. I wanted to switch to the `foo-bar` branch, i.e. I wanted to get the code from the remote `origin/foo-bar` branch into a local branch of the name `foo-bar`, so I did:

```
$ git checkout foo-bar
```

Note that I wasn't sure if I was to say `git checkout origin/foo-bar` or just `git checkout foo-bar`.

Now, I am wondering which of the two did I end up doing?

1. Did I just create a new local branch named `foo=bar` with all the contents of the `master` branch? OR
2. Did I create a new branch named `foo-bar` and automatically pull all contents from the remote `origin/foo-bar` into it?
3. If I did the wrong thing, i.e. I actually wanted to do #2 but if I did something else, how do I delete this local branch named `foo-bar`?

Comment: Did it say anything like "set up to track remote branch"?

Comment: run git status. it should tell you what is your remote branch

Comment: You can see what's happened with e.g. `git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate`.

Comment: No, when I said `git checkout foo-bar`, it said `checking out...x% of y%` thing and took some time and then afterwards, when I did `git branch`, it reported I was on master. When I said, `git branch -a | grep '.*foo-bar$'`, it reported two such branches: `foo-bar` and `origin/foo-bar`.

Comment: One more thing to look at: `git checkout` with no arguments.

Comment: Can you print the result of "git branch -a" this will show you all the branches (remote and local) and tell you which you have checked out).

Comment: why not just check the reflog?

Comment: Between this and your other recent question, I think you may have the wrong mental model for Git's branch system (which would be quite appropriate if you're used to various other version control systems such as Subversion). Git's branch names are merely names for commit hash IDs. The commit objects themselves contain parent commit hash IDs and Git assembles all these into a giant Directed Acyclic Graph (or DAG) to "behave branchily", as it were. This is radically different from even closely related version control systems like Mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

> Note that I wasn't sure if I was to say `git checkout origin/foo-bar` or just `git checkout foo-bar`.

Both of these are valid, but they mean different things. Tl;dr, you wanted the latter in this case.

`origin/foo-bar` (where `origin` in this case is the name of a remote) is a so-called remote tracking branch. Remote tracking branches are read-only and cannot be checked out, so `git checkout origin/foo-bar` will detach `HEAD` and set it to the commit that `origin/foo-bar` refers to.

`git checkout foo-bar` checks out the branch `foo-bar` if it exists, or it creates it anew as described below.

> 1. Did I just create a new local branch named `foo-bar` with all the contents of the `master` branch?

If your version of Git is not ancient, by default `git checkout foo-bar` will create branch `foo-bar` and set it up to track in your case `origin/foo-bar`.

This behaviour is documented in the [man page for git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/2.12.2#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt).

> 2. Did I create a new branch named foo-bar and automatically pull all contents from the remote `origin/foo-bar` into it?

See 1.

> 3. If I did the wrong thing, i.e. I actually wanted to do #2 but if I did something else, how do I delete this local branch named foo-bar?

To delete a branch, check out a different branch (e.g. `git checkout master`) and then do `git branch -d foo-bar`.

See [man page for git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/2.12.2#git-branch--d).